# Pipe separated values in groups of 3 regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
abc|ghy|33d
```

The regex below matches it fine

```
^([\d\w]{3}[|]{1})+[\d\w]{3}$
```

The string changes but the characters separated by the pipe are always in 3's ... so we can have

```
krr|455
```

we can also have

```
ddc
```

Here's where the problem happens: The regex explained above doesn't match the string if there is only one set of letters ... i.e. "dcc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this step by step.

Your regex :

```
^([\d\w]{3}[|]{1})+[\d\w]{3}$
```

We can already see some changes. `[|]{1}` is equivalent to `\|`.
Then, we see that you match the first part (aaa|) at least once (the + operator matches once at least). Also, `\w` matches numbers.
The * operator matches 0 or more. So :

```
^(?:\w{3}\|)*\w{3}$
```

works.

See [here](http://regexr.com/3b3au).

### Explanation

`^` Matches beggining of string
`(?:something)*` matches something zero time or more. the group is non-capturing as you won't need to
`\w{3}` matches 3 alphanumeric characters
`\|` matches |
`$` matches end of string.

Comment: `[\w]` is equivalent to `\w`

Comment: Also you should probably recommend non-capturing groups instead of capturing groups by default... unless it's evident the captures will be used for something. Otherwise great write-up.

Comment: Great point, feel bad that I forgot about this. Thanks again @naomik

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\d\w]{3}(?:[|][\d\w]{3}){0,2}$
```

You simply quantify the variable part.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/18

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regex as below:

```
^([\d\w]{3})(\|[\d\w]{3})*$
```

here first match 3 `alphaNumeric` and then `alphaNum with | as prefix.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA4uH1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a little awkward, but I'm guessing you want to be able to match

```
abc
abc|def
abc|def|ghi
```

You can do that with

```
/^\w{3}(?:\|\w{3}){0,2}$/
```

Visualization

[image: /^\w{3}(?:\|\w{3}){0,2}$/]

Explanation

- `^` — match beginning of string
- `\w{3}` — match any 3 of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- `(? ... )?` — non-capturing group, 0 or 1 matches
- `\|` — literal `|` character
- `$` — end of string

---

If the goal is to match **any** amount of 3-letter segments, you can use

```
/^(?:\w{3}(?:\||$))+$/
```

Comment: This is unecessary complex. Instead of having twice the same group with `?` you could simply use `{0,2}`...

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer too .. i really like the graphic... is that autogenerated somewhere based on the regex or you created it ???